# Building a Jar - how to include resource files? IntelliJ 2017

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

Just to clarify my position on this question:

- I am using absolute paths because without them, my tests fail.
- I think I am failing to understand how to use relative paths.
- As an end result, I want a jar that runs with no file path dependencies.

Been searching. Found no solution that has worked for me...

I have a folder format:

```
src/main/java/packages/javafiles.java (there are several)
src/main/resources/Prolog_Files/fileIWantToLoad.pl
```

in my code, I have to state the absolute path:

```
String currentTheory = "src/main/resources/Prolog_Files/kb.pl";
```

And load it like this:

```
Theory theory = new Theory(new FileInputStream(currentTheory));
```

Such that when I run my JavaFX app, and run tests, it works perfectly.

However, when I build a Jar, I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\Prolog_Files\kb.pl (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I've done a lot of searching for how to make this work; I've tried, and failed to use:

```
File currFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/src/main/resources/Prolog_Files/kb.pl").getFile());
```

and

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("main/resources/Prolog_Files/kb.pl");
```

as well as trying to include the folder as a resource inside of IntelliJ, moving folders around, trying to reference the .pl file without the path information.

Tearing my hair out now after 4 hours of this - please help!

Edit: Just to add, I'm not using Maven, ANT, or anything like this. I am simply using whatever IntelliJ provides.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I've tried without absolute path as well - I'm fairly certain that the jar will take /src as root, but I've also tried to use "resources/Prolog_Files/kb.pl" without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell IntelliJ that you need to include resource directory.

1. Create resource folder where you wish to add external resources
   [image: Create Resource Folder]
2. Make it a resource folder and thats it.
   [image]

**PS:** I would still suggest you not to use Absolute Path, Let me know if I can help you replacing existing one with Relative Path.

Comment: Thanks for your response - In fact, I've already tried to set it as the resource root, I should've said that I did that as one of my attempts. I *DO* wish to make the resulting artifact use relative, rather than absolute paths, so please do let me know how I can properly do this.